# Fetching data from nested array in API React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to fetch data from a nested array from an API in react native.

so my coding is like this

```
export default const App= () =>{

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    console.log(data);

     //Some fetch code here
    //setData happen here
  
    return  (
       <View >
        <Text >fetched data</Text>
          <Text>{data?.data?.items?.newOne?.a}</Text>
          <Text>{data?.data?.items?.newOne?.b}</Text>
          <Text>{data?.data?.items?.newOne?.c}</Text>
       </View>
    )
};
```

and the supposed array is like this

```
arr = { code: 1, data:{ items:[{newOne:{a:2, b:4, c:6}, id:00},], totality: 1}}
```

can someone tell me what I'm doing it wrong here? I'm new to js and also react native. I received blank whenever I run this code.

Comment: what does console.log(data) print?

Comment: It will print {code: 1, data: {item:[[Object], [Object], [Object][Object]], totality: 1}};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is an array, so you have to access it as one

```
return  (
   <View >
    <Text >fetched data</Text>
      <Text>{data?.data?.items[0]?.newOne?.a}</Text>
      <Text>{data?.data?.items[0]?.newOne?.b}</Text>
      <Text>{data?.data?.items[0]?.newOne?.c}</Text>
   </View>
)
```

Comment: actually items is an array of objects, so everything is in a single object at 0th index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
export default const App= () =>{

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    console.log(data);

     //Some fetch code here
    //setData happen here

const itemsObject = data?.data?.items[0] ?? {}

  
    return  (
       <View >
        <Text >fetched data</Text>
          <Text>{itemsObject?.newOne?.a}</Text>
          <Text>{itemsObject?.newOne?.b}</Text>
          <Text>{itemsObject?.newOne?.c}</Text>
       </View>
    )
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @Kay glad it helpd,  do mark as accepted and upvote if you think it helped :)